# Book opening and closing animation css

Tags: html, css

I have been playing with book opening code on w3 schools. I have changed it slightly so that the page opens like a book when hovered upon. I need the page to go back with the reverse animation when not hovered upon.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the hover is removed, the page should go back with the reverse animation.

Comment: You have placed the `transform-origin` inside the `:hover` so it's only applied when the hover starts. When you un-hover, the `transform-origin` reverts to its default.

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/fivera/pen/rHigj